# I get TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context' from pyspark/serializers when get city name by shapely

Tags: python, pyspark, shapely

I want to get city name by latitude and longitude using shapely, and add it to spark dataframe using udf. I save multipolygon as a constant, and want to pass this constant to pyspark udf. However, error shows that "TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'" as [picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk04r.png) and [picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otIrQ.png).

I have try the way to pass a constant to udf as a demo, it works. But when I use shapely library to check city name whether exist in a specific multipolygon or not, it causes the error. Thanks.

```
import os
from copy import deepcopy
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import functions as pyspark_func
from shapely.geometry import Point, asShape


java8_location = '/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.12/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home'
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = java8_location

TRIP_SCHEMA = StructType([
    StructField('trip_id', IntegerType(), False),
    StructField('start_lat', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('start_lon', DoubleType(), True),
])


class TripController:
    def __init__(self, spark, geo_poly_set, poly_shape_set):
        self.__spark = spark
        self.__geo_poly_set = geo_poly_set
        self.poly_shape_set = poly_shape_set
        self.init_udf(self.poly_shape_set)
        self.__trips_dfs = self.__spark.createDataFrame([("151713183", 34.0485, -118.258537),
                                                         ("151716483", 34.069271, -118.296593),
                                                         ("156593713", 33.970242, -118.426071),
                                                         ("156593711", 33.99556, -118.481552),
                                                         ("156617496", 34.047749, -118.243172)],
                                                        ["trip_id", "start_lat", "start_lon"])

        self.__trips_dfs.show()

    def init_udf(self, poly_shape_set):
        # poly_shape_set_la = deepcopy(poly_shape_set['LA'])
        self.__udf_get_city_name_by_coordinates = udf(lambda x, y, p_shape: 'LA' if p_shape.intersects(Point(x, y)) else 'UNKNOWN', StringType())

    def clean_ods_data(self):
        self.__trips_dfs = self.__trips_dfs.withColumn("city_name", TripUdf.is_exist_in_multi_poly(self.poly_shape_set['LA'])
                                    (pyspark_func.col("start_lon"), pyspark_func.col("start_lat")))
        self.__trips_dfs.show()  # ERROR


class TripUdf:
    @staticmethod
    def get_date(time_str: str) -> str:
        date_str, time_str = time_str.split(' ')
        return date_str

    @staticmethod
    def is_exist_in_multi_poly(p_shape):
        print(type(p_shape))  # <class 'shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygonAdapter'>

        def process(x, y, p_shape):
            return 'LA' if p_shape.intersects(Point(x, y)) else 'UNKNOWN'
        return pyspark_func.udf(lambda x, y: process(x, y, p_shape))


class GeoUtils:
    @staticmethod
    def is_exist_in_multi_poly(point_x, point_y, poly_shape):
        """
        Check if point in multiple polygon
        :param point_x: coordinates x
        :param point_y: coordinates y
        :param poly_shape: multipolygon
        :return: boolean
        """
        is_exist = False
        point = Point(point_x, point_y)
        is_exist = poly_shape.intersects(point)
        return is_exist

    @staticmethod
    def get_poly_shape(poly_context):
        """
        Get poly shape
        :param poly_context: multipolygon, json format
        :return: return poly_shape
        """
        # from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon
        # poly_shape = MultiPolygon(poly_context)
        import shapely.geometry
        poly_shape = asShape(poly_context)
        return poly_shape


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initailize spark session
    sconf = SparkConf() \
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g") \
        .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "false") \
        .set("spark.ui.enabled", "true") \
        .setMaster("local")
    spark_session = SparkSession.builder \
        .config(conf=sconf) \
        .appName("Analysis System") \
        .master("local") \
        .getOrCreate()
    spark_session.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    # read multi poly json
    poly_rdd = spark_session.read.json('poly.json') # this json file could be downloaded from https://public.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=us-county-boundaries&q=06037&facet=statefp&facet=countyfp&facet=name&facet=namelsad&facet=stusab&facet=state_name
    poly_json = json.loads(poly_rdd.toJSON().collect()[0])
    geo_poly_set = dict()
    poly_shape_set = dict()
    geo_poly_set['LA'] = poly_json['records'][0]['fields']['geo_shape']  # ['coordinates']
    poly_shape_set['LA'] = GeoUtils.get_poly_shape(geo_poly_set['LA'])

    trip_ctl = TripController(spark_session, geo_poly_set, poly_shape_set)
    trip_ctl.clean_ods_data()
```

Comment: As this question is right now, there is too much extra code which makes it confusing to understand the problem. Try following the guide in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to produce the minimum amount of code which causes the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have already deleted extra code, and make it simple to understand.